# How does ILMerge effect dependencies

Tags: c#, dependencies, ilmerge

How does ILmerge work for something like libraries, where you have multiple dependencies, and the projects using this library may have different versions of the same dependencies?  Does the 'user' of the library also have access to all dependencies in the library...or are those some how closed off?

**Example**

Say we have 3 Projects: `ClassLibrary1`, `ClassLibrary2`, and `Program1`.

`ClassLibrary1` references `ClassLibrary2`

`Program1` references `ClassLibrary1`

In this common scenario, `Program1` can use any of `ClassLibrary2`'s methods or objects.

If we *ILMerge* `ClassLibrary1` and `ClassLibrary2` does `Program1` still have access to everything `ClassLibrary2` has?

Comment: Your example doesn't sound like much of a match with your question.  Having multiple versions of the same dependency is already pretty difficult to deal with in general, it can't work when you merge.

Answer (score 0):

When you `ILMerge` two assemblies then you create a new assembly which contains both of them. So you can reference the either `ClassLibrary2` or new created one to access types of assembly `ClassLibrary2`.

Comment: so if ``Program1`` then references ``ClassLibrary2`` do you have like weird naming conflicts and namespace issues?